# Speaking to upper management without hesitation

Tags: communication

I have been in industry for the last 4 years.

First, let me be direct. I am unable to speak clearly with upper management. Often I get very nervous while speaking to somebody who is very senior to me. My English is not so good so this could be one of the reasons. Can somebody please help me with this issue? I believe there would be many people were in a similar situation. Please guide me.

Comment: Is this software related?  If so I wouldn't worry about it whatsoever - 70% of programmers do speak English, but only as a second language.  Rock on!

Comment: Yes yes I am working as a software developer.

Comment: Read books written by current highly successful business people. Examples are those from Shark's Tank and Dragon's Den: Barbara Corcoran, Arlene Dickinson, Lori Greiner, Mark Cuban, etc. You will see they are quite ordinary people, with extra vision and perserverance. The reading will also help your English studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of situation is quite common. Sometimes your upbringing, your culture and even your age may block out your ability to communicate even with your peers, let alone the management.

Stay assured that it will pass as you progress through your career and your life. If speaking to upper management is part of your job and is inevitable, ask your immediate manager to help your train your communication skills. If this isn't an option, look for communication courses yourself.

Remember that everyone at the company is a person just like you. Everyone is pulling in the same direction to do their jobs, achieve the goals and help the whole company succeed. If you need to talk to anyone, it's because you also want to help the company succeed. Remember that they want to listen to you as well, for the same reason. So don't be afraid, you are only doing your job.